# Using SMB protocol in URL while using JCIFS library on Android

Tags: java, android, smb, jcifs

I'm using JCIFS in my new Android project. Somehow I've decided to use URL class to generalized the file path (so I can add more protocol later). What I did is as below

```
URL url = new URL("smb://192.168.1.1/filepath");
```

And then java.net.MalformedURLException exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: smb
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:184)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
```

Consulting [JCIFS FAQ](http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/faq.html#ukproto) reveals that I have to register the protocol before using the class. However I don't really know how to do so in Android. I think the library do this already, but it doesn't on Android.

So what should I do ?

Comment: Where did you put the jcifs Jar file? It should be in the proper classpath for the Handler to be loaded.

Comment: I put the jar file in the /libs directory of the project, which I think it's not in the classpath.

And I think Android handles classpath differently than the normal Java application do.

Answer (score 8):

I've just saw the usage in JCIFS reference, in the SmbFile reference.

> When using the java.net.URL class with 'smb://' URLs it is necessary
>   to first call the static jcifs.Config.registerSmbURLHandler(); method.
>   This is required to register the SMB protocol handler.

So I add this call and it works properly.

Comment: Javadoc: [http://stderr.org/doc/libjcifs-java-doc/api/jcifs/Config.html#registerSmbURLHandler()](http://stderr.org/doc/libjcifs-java-doc/api/jcifs/Config.html#registerSmbURLHandler())

Comment: Previous link is not available, use https://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/jcifs/Config.html#registerSmbURLHandler%28%29 instead

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a URL object. Pass the URL directly into SmbFile constructor.  For example:

```
SmbFile file = new SmbFile("smb://192.168.1.1/filepath");
```

Then you can do most everything you can do with a regular File.

Comment: The reason I use URL object is I want to support other protocol (and local file system) too. Using URL can make it become more abstract among protocol. Also I want to use Serilizable object to pass between Activities, which SmbFile is not.